# Centos 7 Emergency Mode infinite error

Tags: linux, centos, grub

I cant boot my linux machine due to /etc/fstab having bad lines of code. Currently my machine will attempt to boot and will infinitely loop the message "Welcome to Emergency Mode!..." . I can't get to the console or login.

Hitting escape at the start up screen and entering the rescue mode does not work either. Using grub2 i can see my fstab file via : cat (lvm/centos-root)/etc/fstab.

How can i edit this file and remove the bad lines of code?

Answer (score 1):

Boot from a live DVD, or boot in rescue mode from the installation disk.  If necessary (it probably won't be), manually mount the main system's root partition somewhere (e.g. `/mnt/rescue`).  Edit `/mnt/rescue/etc/fstab` appropriately.  Perform a clean reboot.

Comment: I hit escape while booting and select "CentOS Linux, with Linux 0-rescue" and it boots with the same error.

Comment: That's not what I suggested.  Boot from a bootable Linux DVD, such as a live DVD or the CentOS installation DVD (using *that disk's* rescue mode), not from your hard disk in any mode.  A bootable DVD has its own completely independent Linux system, from which you will be able to access the filesystems on your hard disk (to fix the corrupt file).

Comment: Its a VM and the installation DVD wouldn't launch once it was attached. I ended up finding a working image from last week. Thanks for the help either way!